# Explain this code and how does "not name" is same as "not name != ' ' " also how is "numOfGuests != 0" same as "numOfGuests"same as

Tags: python, python-3.x

[This is the source site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6VtM.png)
i cant get to understand this piece of code,
what does "While not name:" refers to and as mentioned here how could it be same as "not name != '' and how "numOfGuests != 0 " is as same as "if numOfGuests:" 
your help would be appriciated

```
name = ''
while not name: #(1)
    print('Enter your name:')
    name = input()
print('How many guests will you have?')
numOfGuests = int(input())
if numOfGuests: #(2)
    print('Be sure to have enough room for all your guests.') #(3)
print('Done')
```

Comment: See [*truth value testing*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). The empty string and integer 0 are both false values.

Answer (score -1):

In python,the null value means False and Non-null value means True;In this piece of code,when you dose not set the name,the `name` is False,and the cycle will begin,after you set `name` value, `not name`= False, and jump out the cycle